# Qual é a diferença entre "++$variavel" para "$variavel++"?

Tags: php, operadores

Qual é a diferença entre `++$variavel` para `$variavel++`?

Percebo que, quando executo um `for` com as duas formas, os resultados são os mesmos.

Exemplo 1:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) echo $i;
```

Imprime:

```
0
1
2
```

Exemplo 2:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) echo $i;
```

Imprime:

```
0
1
2
```

- Então, qual é a diferença entre as duas formas de incrementação?

Comment: Acrescentar perguntas à pergunta não sei se é muito boa ideia depois de tantas respostas.

Comment: Entendi, Senhor @JorgeB.. e removido

Comment: Realmente, é paia. Eu é que tinha esquecido de perguntar antes. Ia perguntar, mas esqueci. Talvez caiba outra pergunta :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Esse exemplo que você colocou não é muito bom porque a variável é impressa sempre depois do evento que manipula a variável.

Um exemplo melhor seria assim:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 3) {
    echo $i++;
}
```

Isto imprime:

```
0
1
2
```

E ainda:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 3) {
    echo ++$i;
}
```

Isto imprime:

```
1
2
3
```

Ou seja, a primeira forma incrementa a variável após usar o valor atual, e a segunda incrementa antes de usar o valor.

Comment: Também ganhou um -1 sem explicação aparente!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Pois é. Queria saber o que ela tem de errado.

Comment: Acho que o último trecho de código imprime `3` também. Pode ser o motivo do -1.

Comment: Bom, então está corrigido.

Answer (score 11):

Isso são tipos de incremento, chamado de pré-incremento `++$i` e pós-incremento `$i++`.

No `for` ele não fica claro pois é sempre executado após a execução do bloco.

Um exemplo prático para ver a diferença seria:

```
$i = 1;
echo $i; // 1
echo $i++; // 1
echo $i; // 2
echo ++$i; //3
```

Comment: Bom exemplo, amigo! Isso vai ajudar muito quem tem essa dúvida

Answer (score 10):

Você só vai encontrar diferença se usar isto dentro de uma expressão.

Estes são [operadores de pré e pós-incremento](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). Eles são operadores que além de adicionar um ao valor atual da variável, ele muda o valor dela, ou seja, também é um operador de atribuição, produzindo um efeito colateral.

```
++$i
```

é o mesmo que

```
($i += 1)
```

ou ainda

```
($i = $i + 1)
```

Já

```
$i++
```

é o mesmo que

```
$i
($i += 1)
```

ou ainda

```
$i
($i = $i + 1)
```

Quando ele é usado de forma isolada, em um *statement* (que é o caso onde você usou), não faz diferença usar um ou outro. Mas quando está em um expressão, o pré-incremento (`$++x`) fará o incremento, atribuirá o novo valor para a variável e é este valor que será o resultado da operação que será considerado na parte da expressão onde ele foi usado, enquanto que o pós-incremento (`$x++`) considerará o valor original da variável para uso na expressão e só depois fará o incremento, então no final o valor da variável será o mesmo, mas o valor usado na expressão será diferente:

```
$i = 0;
echo $i; //imprime 0
echo $i++; //imprime 0. i agora vale 1, o incremento ocorreu depois de usar o valor de i
echo ++$i; // imprime 2 já que primeiro ele fez o incremento, depois usou o valor
```

Em tese os 6 códigos abaixo fazem a mesma coisa, mas note que no `for` e no primeiro `while` o incremento esta sendo usado como *statement*, e não faz diferença, mas no segundo `while` quando ele está sendo usado como expressão, faz diferença.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) echo $i . "\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) echo $i . "\n";
$i = 0;
while ( $i < 3) { 
    echo $i . "\n";
    $i++;
}
$i = 0;
while ( $i < 3) {
    echo $i . "\n";
    ++$i;
}
$i = 0;
while ( $i < 3) echo $i++ . "\n";
$i = 0;
while ( $i < 3) echo ++$i . "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/pVPVwT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/elyqsbhc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Operators.php).

Não faz diferença na velocidade usar um ou outro.

Alguns programadores acham que não deveria existir um deles para não confundir. Mas como tudo, vai do programador saber usar certo.

Comment: +1 pelo operadores de pré-incremento e pós-incremento. Eu sempre falava com os amigos da programação "coloca um 'mais mais' antes da variável"

Answer (score 4):

São duas formas de incrementação, pré-fixados e  pós-fixados. Ambas fazem a mesma coisa, ou seja, incrementam a variável. Uma diferença pode-se notar no exemplo abaixo:

Exemplo de pós-fixados:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;

if(y == x++) 
printf("São iguais");
else
printf("Não são iguais");
```

Neste exemplo, a saída é: `"Não são iguais"`. Pois o que ele faz primeiro, é verificar se `Y` é igual `X`, e não se `Y` é igual a `X++`, no `IF` ele primeiro verifica e depois incrementa. É um caso importante.

Exemplo de pré-fixados:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;

if(y == ++x) 
printf("São iguais");
else
printf("Não são iguais");
```

Nesse caso, `Y` e `X` serão iguais, logo será impresso `"São iguais"`, pois ele primeiro incrementa o `X` e depois verifica com o `Y`.

Comment: Evite usar snippet quando não é necessário, só atrapalha a resposta.