# É verdade que ++$variavel (pré-incremento) é mais rápido que $variavel++ (pós-incremento)?

Tags: php, desempenho, operadores

É verdade que `++$variavel` é mais rápido que `$variavel++`?

Nessa resposta dada no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756021/3096922), vemos o seguinte trecho:

> ... however pre-incrementing is almost 10% faster, which means that you
>   should switch from post- to pre-incrementing when you have the
>   opportunity ...

Que quer dizer:

> ... no entanto pré-incremento é quase 10% mais rápido, o que significa
>   que você deve mudar a partir de pós para pré-incrementar quando você
>   tem a oportunidade ...

Eles são comprovadamente mais rápidos? Por quê?

Se `pré-incremento` realmente é mais rápido, há alguma razão para eu me preocupar em usar ele, ao invés de `pós-incremento` nos códigos que já o usei? Quero dizer, essa diferença de performasse faz muita diferença na aplicação?

Comment: interessante...10% não é pouca coisa hein

Comment: É 10% em quais casos? qual foi o código que mostrou esse resultado?

Comment: @rray, é aqueles tipos de coisa assim: "ouvi falar que isso é melhor que aquilo" e está nessa questão que vi lá no SOEN

Answer (score 4):

**Edição**

Não sei com o PHP, mas com o C++ (que PHP tem como inspiração), a *única* diferença se encontra quando está se referindo a uma *classe*. [Essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904/1245766) explica a diferença entre `++v` e `v++`. Em resumo:

> Como o compilador não está gerando código, mas simplesmente fazendo chamada a uma função de operator++, não há como otimizar a variável temporária e a construtora de cópia associada. Se essa construtora for custosa em termos de desempenho, então pode ter um impacto significante na performance.

<sub>O original em *inglês*:</sub>

> Since the compiler isn't generating code, but just calling an operator++ function, there is no way to optimize away the tmp variable and its associated copy constructor. If the copy constructor is expensive, then this can have a significant performance impact.

**Resposta original**

A única razão que teria que usar o `$variavel++` é quando é importante para sua aplicação - ou seja, se precisa que o valor esteja incrementado *após* ter lido ele, então será necessário.

[Essa resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80387/4171) explica muito bem as diferenças entre o `++$v` e `$v++`, e quando/como usar cada um (e *quando* faz a diferença).