# Como somar todos os números na sequência no while?

Tags: c, algoritmo

Como somar de 1 a 64 no `while`?

Queria fazer a soma `1+2+3+4+...+64` imprimir o valor do somatório ao chegar no final.

O que tentei até agora:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numero= 1;
    //int resultado;

   while(numero <= 64) {

    printf("%d\n", numero);
    numero++;

    }
return 0;


}
```

Comment: Seria isto que precisa `soma += numero;` (dentro do loop)?

Comment: @gato seria sim. Veja a resposta do Maniero

Comment: vlw pela ajuda manow

Comment: @nazinhopb Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 10):

Se você quer somar deve colocar isso no código. Então precisa de uma variável, obviamente começando do 0, que receba a soma, e precisa somar o novo número a cada passo (o incremento em cada passo você já fez), imagino que a impressão só deve ocorrer no final então deve ficar fora do laço, algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int numero = 1;
    int resultado = 0;
    while (numero < 65) resultado += numero++;
    printf("%d\n", resultado);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JzGZcw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dlmrknzz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumSequence.c).

O `++` está incrementando a variável `numero` em cada passo do laço, ele soma 1 na própria variável, o mesmo que `numero = numero + 1`. E o `+=` está somando o resultado da expressão à direita na variável `resultado`, ele soma na própria variável, o mesmo que `resultado = resultado + numero`. Note que o incremento de `numero` só ocorre depois porque ele é um [pós-incremento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80383/101).

Dá para fazer com `for`, mas acho pior:

```
    int resultado = 0;
    for (int numero = 1; numero < 65; numero++) resultado += numero;
    printf("%d\n", resultado);
```

Comment: Nice. Simples e funcional. Aconselho a explicar o funcionamento do incremento "numero++". Nesta situação pode ficar confuso para o OP.

Comment: Neste momento a resposta pede o uso do ciclo while, mas estou curioso porque acha que o uso do ciclo for seja pior neste caso? O código ficou mais coeso, e o uso da variável `numero` fica "exclusiva" ao ciclo. Devido ao funcionamento interno do for?

Comment: É gosto mesmo. Na verdade idealmente em casos assim seria bom ter o `foreach`

Comment: @Maniero neste caso o ideal é não ter laço. Estou elaborando a resposta "embutindo" o laço dentro de uma fórmula `o(1)`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu até acho, mas não quis dar uma solução diferente porque eu acho que o exercício é justamente o laço. É só fazer `32.5 * 64` que é (64 + 1) / 2 * 64.

Comment: como faço pra exibir o índice do ultimo elemento?

Comment: Que índice? Que elemento? Não tem nada disso nesse código.

Answer (score 2):

Que tal incluir a nível de concepção o laço, mas não a nível de código?

Bem, sua pergunta é claramente matemática. Como tal, poderia ser resolvida matematicamente.

Você tem os números `1, 2, 3..., n`, para um `n` qualquer. Seja o valor dessa soma `S`.

O que acontece se pegarmos essa lista e somar com o inverso dela?

```
1     +  2    +  3    + ... + (n-1) + n
n     + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2     + 1
-------------------------------------------
(n+1) + (n+1) + (n+1) + ... + (n+1) + (n+1)
```

A primeira lista vale `S`. Como é uma soma finita, inverter os elementos não alterará o resultado final, portanto a lista reversa também vale `S`. Isso significa que a soma das duas listas é `2S`. Note que o termo `(n+1)` é repetido `n` vezes, portanto:

```
2S = n*(n+1)
```

Daí:

```
S = n*(n+1)/2
```

Como `n` é um inteiro, `n*(n+1)` necessariamente é um número par. Portanto dividir por 2 resultará em um número inteiro. Para garantir o valor, não custa nada forçar a precedência da multiplicação antes da divisão:

```
( n*(n+1) )/2
```

Então, como se deseja saber o valor para a soma até 64, poderia fazer `(64*65)/2` ou deixar na variável, que ficaria mais fácil alterar para outro valor no futuro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 64;
    printf("%d\n", ( n*(n+1) )/2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 pela resposta bem elaborada. (por um acaso, a solução puramente matemática havia sido mencionada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276505/como-somar-todos-os-numeros-na-sequencia-no-while#comment565115_276512) anteriormente).

Comment: @Bacco sim, de fato. Eu sempre acho importante mencionar que mesmo problemas "naturalmente iterativos" podem possuir algoritmos não iterativos

Comment: Sim, um ótimo complemento e aula de matemática.

Answer (score -1):

Você está a fazer printf de todos os números com esse programa. É preciso criar uma variável (no meu caso, "soma") que junte todos os números.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int numero = 0;
    int soma = 0;

    while(numero < 5) {
        numero++;
        soma = soma + numero;
        printf("%d\n", soma);
    }
}
```

Comment: O que sua resposta acrescenta à do Maniero?

Comment: Agora que reparei, não acrescento nada. Posso apagar a resposta, se pretenderem